# How do I convert a regular JSON object into a Mongo document using Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongoose, document

I have a JSON Object called `parsedSong` that I want to convert into a Mongo document using Mongoose.

```
var newSong = new Song(parsedSong);
```

However, this only provides me with a new document that only has an `id` attribute. How can I make a conversion that doesn't cut my data from `parsedSong`?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the schema definition for `Song` and then contents of `parsedSong`?

Comment: I didn't realize that the Schema limits what kind of information gets defined in the document. My understanding of Schemas is still fuzzy. You and @Prontto really helped! Thanks.

Comment: Have you found the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed you have defined these variables in schema. Then you can make something like this:

```
var bestSong = {
    artist: "Seether",
    song: "Careless Whisper"
};

var song = new Song(bestSong);

song.save(function(err) {
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('saved');
});
```

And now this song should be in database.